# Laravel returns json with object's array with properties with names started with Uppercase

Tags: json, laravel, get

In Laravel I have method that return json with object's array:

```
$filters = DB::table('filters')->get();
return response()->json($filters);
```

In Postman I have response:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "mobile_games"
    }
]
```

Id and Name begins from Uppercase but in json they should start from lowercase: id and name

Comment: The mysql columns aren't Uppercase?

Comment: QueryBuilder returns original column names including the original casing. Your approach could be iterating over the array and renaming the keys with `strtolower()`.

Comment: @MaKobi ok, but what in case when name would be FilterName? After `strtolower()` in json it will be filtername instead filterName